# Match value from a table and print the results on a column

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to build an excel VBA program to find all the match values from a table and print the finding on a column... I tried to use vlookup but only gives me the first location that finds... and I would like all the finds.

here is an example:
my table starts on cell A2

- column A (number)
- 0084
- 0084
- 0085
- 0085
- 0086
- 0087
- column B (location)
- 12AC5
- 16AC5
- 02AC5
- 06AC5
- 01DC5
- 11DC5

on column D I paste the values I am looking for there location..... on column F would give me all the location found that matches my request... in ascending order or any order

for example I am looking for the location of 2 numbers:

- column D (I paste the number that I what to see there location
- 0084
- 0087

I expect to see the results:

- column F(found location)
- 12ac5
- 12bd5
- 16ac5

Any help with this would be very much appreciated..

Cheers,
JFFC
excel VBA

```
enter code here
```

Comment: Your sample data is confusing.  Perhaps paste a csv version of your data with your expected results???

Comment: thanks for the tip Christian... I tried many ways to improve it... I think this is the best I can do...Cheers JFC

Comment: The built-in "Advanced Filter" can do this - see http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel/HP100739421033.aspx

Comment: Thanks.... I have been looking on the microsoft web site... I will keep playing with "Advanced Filter" so far no breaking news yet...

Cheers JFC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clarification required. Are you:

Wanting to search for multiple values (in column A), return all the corresponding values(in column B) into column F?

An example of this is:

A, B,  D, F
1,loc1,1,loc1
1,loc2,2,loc2
2,loc3, ,loc3
3,loc4, , 
3,loc5, , 
4,loc6, ,

Showing that if you serach for 1 and 2 (in column D) you get back Loc1, loc2 and loc3 because these are all the locations that match the numbers 1 and 2?

If this isnt what u are trying to do then i am confused

Macro to achieve this:

```
Sub FindLocations()

Dim ValueCell As Range
Dim SearchCell As Range
Dim ResultCounter As Integer
Dim ValueCol, LocCol, SearchCol, ResultCol As Integer

ValueCol = 1 'Look for the values in this column'
LocCol = 2 'Locations are in this column'
SearchCol = 4 'The search values are in this column'
ResultCol = 6 'Spit out the results in this column'

ResultCounter = 2

For Each ValueCell In Range(Cells(2, ValueCol), Cells(ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count, ValueCol))

    For Each SearchCell In Range(Cells(2, SearchCol), Cells(ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count, SearchCol))
        If SearchCell.Value = ValueCell.Value Then
            Cells(ResultCounter, ResultCol).Value = Cells(ValueCell.Row, LocCol).Value
            ResultCounter = ResultCounter + 1
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
Next
End Sub
```

Paste that into your Excel VBA screen (Alt+F11) and run it (or link it to a button) Whenever you want to search click it

The results of this look like this:
[Excel Example http://img97.imageshack.us/img97/9310/excelexample.jpg](http://img97.imageshack.us/img97/9310/excelexample.jpg)

Comment: Your first part is correct....

"column A" is my reference on the table and the corresponding values are on (column B)

" column F" is my output... 

"column D" is my request...

so the plan is... if I want to get the output for a few numbers I past the numbers on "column D".... it will search and match with column A... when it finds it will grab what ever is on "column B" and paste on "column F"

It is same as the lookup formula... I have a number on "column D" it will lookup on "column A"... if is a match will grab the value on "column B" and print on "column F"...

Comment: I reason that lookup does not work for me is because on gives me the first matching value that finds on "column A"...it does not keeo searching for the next matching value... by the way "column D" and "column F" they don't match...."column D" is my input... "column F" is my output.... and of course "column A" and "column B" are part of the table.... Thanks for your time..Cheers JFC

Comment: The only excel way to do this is VBA. When you want more than one cell to be changed by an operation you need a macro. The macro you are after is a For Each loop on Each Range in Column A. If the cell is the value you are looking for, get the value in column B, paste it into column F, continue. Code pasted below

Comment: VBA macro above. You can change the columns by changing the variables ending in Col, comments in the code should explain this

Comment: Thanks a million... it scans over 14 thousand plus rows very fast ..were use to take hours and hours to do the same manually ....this is supper fantastic... thanks again.. cheers JFC

Comment: No prob, performance is about as good as i can get it, but if you want i can add a few small incremental gains for thousand column scans

Comment: No... this is perfect... thanks again for you time...Cheers, JFC